# Storing SQL Connection details - how can I encrypt per-user safely?

Tags: .net, configuration, encryption

I have an application that connects to a number of SQL Servers for monitoring and other tasks. Currently, I only support trusted authentication, since I don't have to store anything sensitive. I want to add the ability to use SQL Authentication (username/password).

What's the best approach to storing this sensitive data between sessions? Is there a user-only certificate or encryption key available to me that I can use? Is it safe enough to use a registry key that's generated randomly per-user to encrypt this information? If there's a way I can use a key (or create one and store it) in such a way that no other user on the computer can access it, that's ideal.

I understand encryption, so I'm not looking for a tutorial - I'm looking for the safest method to keep one user's configuration data for my application safe from other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Data Protection API (aka. DPAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx). Each use has a key that is protected by its password. You store the password/connection string in a the .config file and .Net framework has methods to encrypt/decrypt a config section with a machine key, an user key or an RSA key. Don't reinvent the wheel doing your own custom scheme. And using a registry key is definitely a bad idea. Security comes from secrets, not from access protecttion: it must rely on the user providing a secret (its password at login time), not on a unnaccessible registry key.

[How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

Comment: It appears that I can use the DPAPI, and store a key in the user store, so it's not accessible to any other users on the machine. This looks to be exactly what I want to do - thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of the same here: http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Remus said, use DPAPI. But instead of using PInvoke methods (as in your linked example), use the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class. That is a managed wrapper around DPAPI. A lot of the examples use PInvoke to access DPAPI because there was no managed way to do it before .Net 2.0. The [DataProtectionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope.aspx) class enables you to encrypt/decrypt data for the current user or machine.

Comment: Noted - I dislike the invokes as well, and it's nice to know that there's a managed wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

As Remus pointed out, there is user/machine level encryption available.

i'm generally terrified of such things because that data can be lost relativly easily.

If i were you i'd roll my own system. Encrypt the connection strings using a key hard-coded in your application, convert to Base64, and store the resulting, encrypted, connection strings in the registry.

---

The following function takes a string, encrypts it with AES-256 and the specified key, and base64's the result so it's back as a printable string:

**Sample Usage:**

```
String connectionString = EncryptString(
     "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Lithium;User Id=sa;Password=hello",
     "A fairly complicated password, like a guid: 8B4B0D73-84C9-4A1E-8DD2-9A189F84FD9B");


public static string EncryptString(string source, string key)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt);
    byte[] derivedKey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(derivedKeySize);


    Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();

    rijndael.Mode = cipherMode;
    rijndael.Padding = paddingMode;
    rijndael.KeySize = keySize;
    rijndael.BlockSize = blockSize;
    rijndael.FeedbackSize = blockSize; // no bigger than the blocksize

    rijndael.Key = derivedKey;
    rijndael.IV = iv;

    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);

    byte[] target = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(target);
}

public static string DecryptString(string source, string key)
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt);
    byte[] derivedKey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(derivedKeySize);

    Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create();

    rijndael.Mode = cipherMode;
    rijndael.Padding = paddingMode;
    rijndael.KeySize = keySize;
    rijndael.BlockSize = blockSize;
    rijndael.FeedbackSize = blockSize; // no bigger than the blocksize

    rijndael.Key = derivedKey;
    rijndael.IV = iv;

    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
    byte[] target = transform.TransformFinalBlock(decoded, 0, decoded.Length);

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(target);
}

    private static readonly byte[] iv = {
        0x30,0xA6,0x65,0xDE,0x8C,0x63,0x17,0x44,
        0xB6,0xFD,0xEA,0x5F,0x76,0xA1,0x1C,0x5F
    };

    private static readonly byte[] salt = {
        0xF9,0x39,0x0C,0xE0,0x22,0xE0,0x8E,0x84,
        0xB2,0x05,0x1E,0xA8,0x6D,0x1C,0x39,0xAC
    };

    private const int keySize = 256;
    private const int blockSize = 128;
    private const CipherMode cipherMode = CipherMode.CBC;
    private const PaddingMode paddingMode = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    private const int derivedKeySize = 32;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any form of encryption is only as strong as the methods used to protect the encryption key, and most systems still struggle to truly separate the protected data from its key or other decryption method. For example, an attacker who gets access to a password database can first launch an offline dictionary attack to obtain user passwords, then log in as these users and “legitimately” request the online service provider to perform decryption. Even worse, an insider or a persistent attacker who obtains the encryption key can download the entire database and perform decryption offline.

To defend against such attacks, external crypto services can completely separate encrypted data from the decryption functionality. This ensures that data encryption cannot be reverse-engineered and any decryption must be authorized with the cooperation of the crypto service – even offline.

Take a look at this framework that will help you with per-user encryption: https://virgilsecurity.com/purekit-mariadb-plugin/

The framework provides the following features:

**Password-hardened encryption.** You won’t store users passwords or its hashes. PureKit protects user or internal passwords from data breaches and both online and offline attacks.

**Per-user encryption.** PureKit features strong and fast data encryption of any size file on a per-user basis.

**Role-based encryption.** PureKit provides you with functionality  to create and manage groups (roles), and use scopes (permissions) to allow and deny their access to encryption keys that are used encrypt to resources like files and data

**Secure Data and Files Sharing.** PureKit allows you and your users securely share data using Virgil key management services.

**Encryption occurs independently of database security.** PureKit provides end-to-end encryption, therefore, data security doesn’t rely on any device, network or cloud provider

**Post-Compromise Security.** By requiring simultaneous access to the database and the remote crypto server to unlock protected records, PureKit allows you to protect sensitive data like PII, PHI, and passwords from unauthorized access even if the database or other online storage facility is compromised.

**Zero-knowledge of user passwords and secret keys.** PureKit provides data and password encryption in a way that prevents any possibility for unauthorized parties to know anything about a password or encryption key. Also, Virgil Security has no access to your data.

**Instant invalidation of stolen databases.** PureKit allows rotating keys and records remotely, in case the database has been stolen.